# Exported SVG produces strange white spots

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export

I'm trying to export the attached logo as an SVG, but when I do I get some strange white areas.

[image: logo]

I didn't make the logo, some other designer made this and now the company said they should have it as SVG.

It's made with lots of clipping masks.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/101253/84899

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bizarre Illustrator error - SVG output looks different](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101242/bizarre-illustrator-error-svg-output-looks-different)

Answer (score 1):

The first designer save it as low resolution pdf not a full Vector (.pdf, .ai or .cdr ). If you open it. It will give you same appearance but the colors are chopped into many clipping masks. These one is big wall for an editor especially for the gradients that the original maker did for these one. These white lines or spaces show because of your SVG file settings. It can Identify the gaps of the clipping masks.

And then you will again Re-Save it to .svg /Scalable Vector Graphics. It should be good file. (depends on your svg file settings to make it higher or lower resolution)

Try Re-Saving in SVG with highresolution.

[image]

If the white /blank areas persist, call a doctor:-/ ..joke

Any way the Original file is there even it is chopped-chopped by clipping mask you can re-create it by manualy or UN-Clip all of them (tedious job of cleaning)

If you go to outline view (Ctrl+Y) you can see the original shapes color which is  rectangle ones and the clipper are the irregular shapes. Using the color picker you can copy the exact color. Copy first then delete the rectangles with color.