# Circle inside a circle when I export the inside circle is not fully touching the outter

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating the first circle then I am copying it and I am transforming it minus the stroke of the bigger one then I cut the outter circle. In illustrator everything looks good, but when I save it they are not fully touching. How can I fix that and is there a better way to do it?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg

Comment: @Scott Any tip how to overlay them?

Comment: Looks like a possible lack of precision due to not enough decimal places when exporting the SVG. In the export dialog choose "More Options", and set the decimal places to 3. Or if conflation is a problem as per Scott's link, outset the inner circle by a tiny amount.

Comment: related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73601/is-there-a-reason-hillary-clintons-logo-has-hidden-notches

Answer (score 3):

The problem might come from one or more of these issues:

1. **Conflation error.** Shapes just touching each other can't be rendered properly. See [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65058/image-looks-embossed-when-converted-to-svg) mentioned in comments.
2. **Deformation of Bezier curves.** A circle in Illustrator isn't round to begin with. Every time you add or subtract shapes it will deform slightly.
3. **Not enough decimal places in the SVG.** See [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/101242/bizarre-illustrator-error-svg-output-looks-different). I don't think this is the issue here though.

Issues 1 and 2 can easily be avoided by making sure shapes overlap like this:

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer I will accept I kinda fixed it with the decimal, but it still visible with black fill, just one more thing I updated the question. I forgot to mention that I want the stroke to have round caps is there a way to do it with your way? I tried rounding the anchors, but it's not the same effect.

Comment: Oh you changed the shape! Now it's more complicated. Perhaps just increase the size of the smaller circle a tiny bit so there is an overlap?